# SwiftUI isPresented Environment not updated for sheet dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Given the following minimal reproducible example:

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @State private var showSheet = false
  
  var body: some View {
    return Button("Show sheet") {
      showSheet.toggle()
    }.sheet(
      isPresented: $showSheet,
      onDismiss: {
        print("Parent onDismiss")
      },
      content: {
        NavigationView {
          SheetView(parentShowSheet: $showSheet)
        }
      }
    )
  }
}

struct SheetView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
  @Environment(\.isPresented) private var isPresented
  @Binding var parentShowSheet: Bool
  
  var body: some View {
    Button("Manual close") {
      dismiss()
    }
    .onChange(of: isPresented) { isPresented in
      print("Sheet isPresented", isPresented)
    }
    .onChange(of: parentShowSheet) { parentShowSheet in
      print("Sheet parentShowSheet", parentShowSheet)
    }
  }
}
```

The `SheetView`'s `onChange` methods are not triggering in the way I would expect. In this example there are two ways to close a sheet once it's opened :

1. Click the "Manual close" button which triggers `dismiss()`, or
2. Pull down the sheet to trigger an "interactive close" (the thing that is disabled when `.interactiveDismissDisabled(true)` is added to the view).

If you try these both out you'll see that for (1) you'll get two print statements "Sheet parentShowSheet" and "Parent onDismiss", while for (2) you'll just get one print statement "Parent onDimiss".

Three questions:

- Why does "Sheet parentShowSheet" not print in case (2)?
- Why does "Sheet isPresented" not print in either case? I'd think that dismissing a sheet is very literally changing it's `Environment(\.isPresented)` value.
- How can I add a hook *inside of the `SheetView`* that triggers when it is dismissed with either method (1) or method (2) (e.g. something that operates like either of my onChange methods, but actually works in both cases)?

Comment: Enter parentShowSheet.toggle() inside the button the SheetView guy.

Comment: But that won't work for case (2) right?

Comment: Taking into account help description for `isPresented` env value you can only read it inside view to know if it is presented now or now. `onChange` does not work because once view has removed it is not operable, ie there is nobody to listen `didSet`. Actually I never used this value, need to think where/when it can be helpful. BTW, why do you need it?

Comment: I have a detail view that I normally save to my persistence layer when isPresented changes to false. This detail view is typically accessed via a parent view NavigationLink and navigating back triggers the onChange, which triggers the save. However if I show this same view in a sheet, which I sometimes want to do elsewhere in the app, the changes don't save using that same method (as indicated in the question). My work around is just to pass a variable indicating if the detail view is presented as a sheet, then save incrementally as I make changes in that case.

Comment: I can't get the isPresented environment var to change at all when used on a View inside a sheet modifier. When the sheet is shown, isPresented is already true. When dismissed it isn't changed to false.

Comment: It might be an issue from Apple from the document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/ispresented